# Function name collision in shared objects

Tags: c, odbc, shared-libraries

I'm porting an `ODBC` driver from `Windows` to `Linux`.
The driver is written in `C`.
The way `ODBC` works on `Linux` is that the application makes a call to an ODBC Manager (`ODBCM`), which in turn loads the appropriate driver and passes the function call on.

Assume my driver, which is compiled into a shared object, exposes two functions `A` and `B`.
What is supposed to happen is the `ODBCM` is calls function `A`, and function `A` is calls function `B`.
What is actually happening is that when function `A` calls function `B` instead a function `B'` (which has the same name as `B`, is located in the `libodbc` shared object and is loaded by `Linux` using `ODBC` applications) is invoked.

I feel like there should be either a compile time flag, or a post compilation library modification tool that will correct this issue.
At present I'm going through the library one function at a time doing the following:

```
_B(){ // rename old functions
  ...
}
B() { // add new wrapper function
  return _B(); // which just calls old
}

_A() {
  ... 
  _B(); // Change calls to renamed functions
  ... 
}
```

Which is slow to change and feels kludgy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try linking your `.so` with the `-Bsymbolic` linker option (pass `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` on the gcc command line). This binds all library-internal symbols at link-time so they will not undergo any dynamic linking later.

Comment: This solved the problem! Thank you, saved me a ton of time manually renaming functions and writing wrappers.

Comment: Could you explain what "binds all library-internal symbols at link-time" means and how it solves this problem? It sounds like you're saying this flag causes static linking from a shared lib, is that right? And a program linked with this flag wouldn't need to access the shared lib at runtime? If I figure this out myself before you have a chance to respond I'll add an edit. Thanks.